# Is truncate load and Full load same in ETL?

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, dataloader

What is the difference between Truncate load and Full load with respect to data load in target table ?

Comment: These are non specific labels and don't have a specific meaning. Truncate means delete everything in a table. Generally speaking they probably mean the same thing but you'd have tp reference where you heard these terms

Comment: Truncate refers to what you are doing with the existing data in your target table (See @Nick.McDermaid definition). Full load refers to your source data: full load means load all data in the source table; the other option is an incremental load where you only load records that have changed in the source table since the last load. So both types of process are in theory independent